# Issue with finding the longest increasing sub sequence

Tags: c#

I wrote this method for finding the longest increasing sub sequence in an array. My question is, after checking if the next index is higher in the second `for` loop, why do I have to even use the `else` block afterwards? It doesn't output a correct result if I don't. Why wouldn't it just be sufficient to increment `currentSeq` by `1` if the next one in the sequence is bigger? If `false`, than just move on with the flow of control, with currentSeq being left at `1` anyway?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] nums = new int[length];

    int currentSeq = 1;
    int maxSeq = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] < nums[i + 1])
        {
            currentSeq++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentSeq = 1;
        }

        if (currentSeq > maxSeq)
        {
            maxSeq = currentSeq;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(maxSeq);
}
```

Comment: Consider a sequence like `12123`. After the first 2 numbers you have to start a new sequence, but `currentSeq` is `2`, not `1`. Without resetting it to `1`, the following sequence length will be `4` instead of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the else keyword to reset currentSeq to 1 for the next sequence calculation. Imagine that you're done with the first sequence and you start calculating the next one in the table, you'll need to restart from 1.